# Unable to sort without using itemgetter

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, graph

I am unable to sort in python.

This is what I am able to get. Sorted according to the score.

```
[(('D', 'E'), 0.5), (('D', 'C'), 0.0), (('D', 'B'), 0.0), (('D', 'A'),0.0)]
```

Second step: This is what I want:

```
[(('D', 'E'), 0.5), (('D', 'A'), 0.0), (('D', 'B'), 0.0), (('D', 'C'),0.0)]
```

The output is first sorted according to the score and any ties on the score is sorted according to the second element/node in the tuple.

How can I solve it without using item getter?

```
for n in set(graph.nodes()) - set(graph.neighbors(node)):
    neighbors2 = set(graph.neighbors(n))
    if n != node:
        #print (n, node)
        scores.append(((node,n), 1. * len(neighbors & neighbors2) / len(neighbors | neighbors2)))
        print (scores)
    s = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) # sorted according to scores
    d = sorted(s, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: can you provide the input, as well as the full code you are using?

Comment: please update your question with the code, not just a comment. It is not readable in comments. Thanks.